# phpmailer change mail sender

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I send mail from phpmailer and I wanted to response I get response e-mail address like admin@domain.com. But I want change it to office@domain.com. 
So I added:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('office@domain.com', 'First Last');
```

But in e-mails to response I get both (office and admin) and I want only office@domain.com
I changed it to:

```
$mail->Sender='admin@domain.pl'; 
$mail->SetFrom('office@domain.pl','First Last');
```

I get

```
SMTP Error: Data not accepted.    
SMTP server error: 5.7.1 Forged sender address:
```

My phpmailer version is: 5.2.6

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply to addresses needed to be added before the from address:

```
 $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');
 $mail->setFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'Mailbox name');
```

With this order all is OK.

**addReplyTo** not ***AddReplyTo***

Alternative:
You can clear replyTo array before:

```
 $mail->ClearReplyTos();     
 $mail->addReplyTo(example@example.com, 'EXAMPLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Sender` is the correct approach to do this, so you're doing that right. The error you are seeing is probably down to SPF checks at the receiver - if the sender domain has SPF set up and it does not allow sending from your IP, it will reject it with the error you are seeing.