# how to php email change `setfrom`

Tags: php

how to change `setfrom` in email sending by php

example I have the sender email is `myemail1@gmail.com` and I want change the setfrom when email is sending to `myemail2@gmail.com`

I tried with this code but not work

`$mail->setFrom('myemail2@gmail.com', 'My Email2');`

Comment: Are you using php mailer for sending email?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701411/phpmailer-change-mail-sender

Comment: yes using php mailer.. hmm I think my code looks same with your reference..