# change sender e-mail address

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to change the sender's email address to some dynamic value.

I am following this question link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701411/phpmailer-change-mail-sender) and tried the solution, but still the sender's email is the same as SMTP account username.

Here:

```
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->Username = "rakesh@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = 'password';
        $mail->SetFrom($SenderEmail, $SenderName);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($SenderEmail,$SenderName);
```

But the email header looks like this:

```
$SenderName <rakesh@gmail.com>
```

How can I change this?

Comment: What value does $SenderName have?

Comment: Does Gmail allow sending from other addresses? Won't they simply use the authenticated account when sending? I mean, they probably don't want people to use their SMTP to spoof other addresses.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov some value generated from query.. but does it matter?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah .. that makes sense... so we can't change the sender if using SMTP GMAIL as a host?

Comment: I wouldn't do that either way. A lot of mail servers check if the sending server (in this case Gmails SMTP-server) has permission to send emails using that address. If it doesn't have specific permissions, the mail server will block it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, gmail does not allow you to set arbitrary sender addresses. It does allow you to define a limited number of preset aliases in your account settings, but you can't set random addresses at the point of sending. If you do, it will just ignore it and use your account address instead, as you're seeing. This is mentioned in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.